# Oracle slow performance using subquery inside IN clause

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, subquery

I have query like this:

```
SELECT
  xmlelement("objects",
    xmlagg(
        xmlelement("object",
          xmlelement("accountId", ACCOUNTS.accountId),
          xmlelement("address", ACCOUNTS.ADDRESS)
      )
    )
    INTO obj_info_xml
    FROM 
      ACCOUNTS
    WHERE account_code IN (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(accountCodes), '/accountCode/text()') as accountCode
                 FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(X, '//accountCodes/accountCode'))) accountCodes);
```

When I hardcode values inside `IN` clause then query executes fast, but when I use subquery to select from xml then I can't get results because it executes very slow. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Couple of suggestions... some swear that replacing IN with EXISTS will offer performance advantages but it's questionable how much improvement you will have - still it's an easy change to try. What I think might help more, however, is using subquery factoring (using a WITH statement) for your subquery. The parser will then decide whether it wants to treat your query like an inline view or if it wants to create a temp table to store the values. Either way you should see a performance gain. Read about subquery factoring here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause

Comment: This is what happens when a RDBMS is used as a data store for XML instead of a RDBMS.

Comment: Not sure which version you are on, but have you looked at using [XML indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_indexing.htm#ADXDB0500). If the XPATH lookup is the bottleneck, this should help in speeding that up.

Comment: My gut instinct would be to move away from xmlsequence, extract and extract value and go with xmltable instead. However, without sample data and the ddl of your accounts table, you make it much more difficult to help you. Please update your question to include the extra information.

Comment: Dank could you provide some example how I could change IN clause with WITH clause, because I can't figure out.

Comment: Tom H I don't store XML in database. I'm passing XML with accountCodes to function.

Comment: To use subquery factoring, take the subquery in your `IN` statement (`SELECT EXTRACT... accountCodes`) and wrap it in in a `WITH` statement at the beginning of your query. So it will look like `WITH subquery AS (--IN statement details)`, then your entire query above but the last line will read `WHERE account_code IN (subquery)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x` is a PL/SQL variable containing the list of your account codes, something like this ought to speed things up a little bit:

```
select xmlelement("objects",
                  xmlagg(xmlelement("object",
                                    xmlelement("accountId", accounts.accountid),
                                    xmlelement("address", accounts.address))
                         )
                 ) account_xml
into   obj_info_xml
from   accounts a
       inner join xmltable('//accountCodes/accountCode'
                           passing x
                           columns account_code varchar2(30) path '.') xdata  -- amend datatype as appropriate
         on a.account_code = xdata.account_code;
```

N.B. untested, due to lack of sample data.

---

Ok, what does the following give you?

```
select xmlelement("objects",
                  xmlagg(xmlelement("object",
                                    xmlelement("accountId", accounts.accountid),
                                    xmlelement("address", accounts.address))
                         )
                 ) account_xml
into   obj_info_xml
from   accounts a
where  a.account_code in (select /*+ dynamic_sampling(xdata 10) */ 
                                 account_code
                          from   xmltable('//accountCodes/accountCode'
                                          passing x
                                          columns account_code varchar2(30) path '.') xdata); -- amend datatype as appropriate
```

Another suggestion would be to replace `/*+ dynamic_sampling(xdata 10) */` with `/* cardinality(xdata <roughly expected number of rows>) */` (overwriting with the relevant number, of course).

Also, can you edit your question to provide the execution plans for the query with and without the hardcoded variables, please?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this is also slow as my original query

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple of suggestions which may be of use.